# Error in installing quandl on python and anaconda

Tags: python

I am new to python while installing quandl i am getting below error. I am
using ipython through anaconda.

Please help me with below error.

```
pip install quandl
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement quandl (from versions)

Comment: Which version of python and conda are you using?

Comment: Do `conda install quandl` instead.